# Check file in used by C# code

Tags: c#

What is the quickest way to check that a file is in used via C# code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work :

```
    public bool FileIsLocked(string fileName)
    {
        FileStream fs;
        try
        {
            fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
            fs.Dispose();
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

u can try to open this with deny other app access it.

When u get exception, u will know this file is used by other.